# How to get not encoded characters in response of http post in Python

Tags: python, json, unicode, request, response

I’m calling GraphQL API via http post, as:

```
result = json.dumps(requests.post(url, json={'query': query}).json(), indent=2)
```

In result I see some characters are converted to their Unicode codes, like: `\u00c2\u00ae\u00c2` but I wish to get actual characters there, like: `Â®Â`.
When I’m doing the same with curl command, I’m getting these characters.
I’ve tried to use `.text` property. Tried `.decode('utf8')` but still getting codes not actual character.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json.dumps() function has an option "ensure_ascii" which is "True" on default. This way all characters in the json string will be ascii characters. Just add ensure_ascii=False to your json.dumps() call and it should do what you want.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump